# C# Exception causes my form to close

Tags: c#, exception, formatexception

When I throw a FormatException, the form always seems to close. Is there a way that the form doesn't close so I can do actions on the form?

Example:

```
    int postcodeNumeriek = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(postcode.Text, out postcodeNumeriek) == false)
    {
        throw new FormatException("De postcode heeft een verkeerd formaat");
    }

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@naam", familienaam.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@voornaam", voornaam.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@straat", straat.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nummer", nummer.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bus", bus.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postcode", postcode.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gemeente", gemeente.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telefoonnummer", telefoonnummer.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@btwnummer", btwNummer.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nieuwsbrief", nieuwsbrief.Checked);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emailadres", emailAdres.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@klantnummer", klantID);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    cmd = new SqlCeCommand("UPDATE Klanten SET Actief=0 WHERE ID='" + recordID + "'", Klantenbeheer.HuidigeDatabaseVerbinding);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (FormatException e)
{
    postcode.Focus();
}
```

In this example, I want my postal code to generate an exception when it is formatted incorrectly. When this happens, the form just closes so the postcode.Focus(); doesn't get executed.

Maybe it does but it's not visible.

Comment: have you stepped through with a debugger to ensure the the exception thrown is actually the one you're throwing and not another?

Comment: You could also simply use `Int.Parse` instead of `Int.TryParse` since the former will throw a `FormatException` if it can't parse the string.

Comment: I have been debugging and I see now that the form get's closed anyway by a this.Close() in my code even if the exception is reached. I don't seem to be able to answer my own question just yet

Comment: @Dirk You have that backwards...it's good that OP is using TryParse().

Comment: @Flybersite Why are you throwing an exception?  If the intent is to inform the user, why not a MessageBox() and a graceful exit?

Comment: @DonBoitnott Look at the code again please. He throws an exception if `TryParse` returns false, so he might as well use `Parse` instead.

Comment: @Dirk True, which is why I question the entire methodology.

Comment: Further...it's silly to try and throw an exception to yourself.  Just deal with the failure you already know about in a more graceful manner.

Comment: Is Exception Handling not the system that it is designed for this type of stuff? I mean, there is a problem with the data so I use an exception to tell the user there is a problem.

Comment: @DonBoitnott Using Parse returns the following error: Cannot convert type 'int' to 'bool'

Comment: @Flybersite Using Parse() was Dirk's idea, not mine.  Regardless, my suggestion is that you stop throwing the exception and instead report it in a less destructive way and gracefully exit the routine when parsing fails and you cannot continue.  `throw` is a pretty abrupt way to handle this...unless you really mean for it to be a crashing blow.

Answer (score 0):

Ik denk dat het handiger is als je die FormatException weg haalt. 
En de textbox bijvoorbeeld vult met wat tekst waar in staat dat het formaat niet klopt.

I think it would be better to remove the FormatException.
The tryparse is fine. But just fill the textbox with some info.

```
int postcodeNumeriek = 0;

if (int.TryParse(postcode.Text, out postcodeNumeriek) == false)
{
    postcode.Text ="format postalcode incorrect";
}
```

and in these cases its always good to use the Try statement.